# Combine Two API To send Data To Back-End

Tags: angular, typescript, api, observable

I've single form with two api need to be send to backend. I show some code as a reference. I just show the problematic part.
I need when user click submit form, first it must be checking organization Id already exist or not. If it exists than throw error message. My problem is when organization id already exists it does not throw error message. how to make it happen

**Service**

```
     public signupform(userData: SignupRequest): Observable<any>{
   let userid = userData.userId;

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:9080/project/api/auth/createorganisation')
    .pipe
    (tap( // Log the result or error
      data => {
        if (data.status['message'] === 'Success.') {

      switchMap(() => this.http.post('http://localhost:9080/project/api/auth/createuser')
      .pipe(catchError((error) => {return empty()}))

      )
        }else{
          throw new Error(data.status['message']);

        }
      },

    )
    )
  }
```

Comment: Does your `POST /api/auth/createorganisation` throw an error message if the organization Id already exists?

Comment: No.. It doesn't throw any error message when organization Id already exists

Comment: Only `post /api/auth/createuser` throw an error message

Comment: If `POST /api/auth/createorganisation` did throw an error, then you could likely handle this more elegantly.

Comment: where did you get that organization id from form? from a dropdown?  if yes then you can hit organization check service after selecting from dropdown. there is no need to check on form submission.

Comment: @FarhatZaman Thanks for your comment... Organization id from user input not from dropdown...

Comment: @swapy you mean user need to provide organization id? can u explain the flow how you get user id in input, like from user or by some other source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:9080/project/api/auth/createorganisation')
    .pipe(switchMap((data:any)=>{
          //you get the result
         if (data.status['message'] === 'Success.')
             return this.http.post('http://localhost:9080/project/api/auth/createuser')
         else 
           return throwError(data.status['message'])
    }))
```

well, if create user can return data.status['message'] === 'Success.' or not, we can make another switchmap

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:9080/project/api/auth/createorganisation')
     .pipe(switchMap((data:any)=>{
          //you get the result
         if (data.status['message'] === 'Success.')
             return this.http.post('http://localhost:9080/project/api/auth/createuser')
         .pipe(switchMap((data:any)=>{
             if (data.status['message'] === 'Success.')
                 return of(data)
             else
                 return throwError(data.status['message'])
         }))
         else 
           return throwError(data.status['message'])
    }))
```

See that we use throwError (a 'rxjs' create observable), NOT new Error

In general we subscribe like

```
this.service.signupform(data).susbcribe(
    (res)=>{console.log(res)},
    (error)=>{console.log(error)}
)
```

but you can take **another aproach** that you service always return a value

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:9080/project/api/auth/createorganisation')
     .pipe(switchMap((data:any)=>{
          //you get the result
         if (data.status['message'] === 'Success.')
             return this.http.post('http://localhost:9080/project/api/auth/createuser')
         .pipe(map((data:any)=>{
             if (!data.status['message'] === 'Success.')
                 return {error:data.status['message']}
         }))
         else 
           return of({error:data.status['message']})
    }),catchError((error)=>{
        return of({error:error})
    })
```

So, you subscribe like

```
this.service.signupform(data).susbcribe(
    (res)=>{
      if (res.error){
         ....
      }
      else
        console.log(res)}
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer... If `post http://localhost:9080/project/api/auth/createuser ` already have user id, It can throw error message too?

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry if there're sintax errors, -I'm in hurry-